# How to refresh parent window which is standard vf page of lightning when the same page helped in obtaining a new window?

Tags: custom-field, lightning, pagereference, redirect

I have a custom made action in the standard contact page(call it "myaction") and to that action i have given a another URL say "/apex/mypage" . So when you click on the action "myaction" it redirects you to the page "mypage".

I am doing this using page reference, the standard way. For clear understanding i have the page below

<-----------------myaction is linked to vf page apex1------------------>

```
<apex:page controller="mycontroller" action="{!redirect}">
</apex:page>
```

<-----------------------controller: mycontroller ----------------------->

```
global class mycontroller{
public Contact contact {get;set;}

 public mycontroller(){
  Id id = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
  contact= (id == null) ? new Contact() :[SELECT AccountId, Phone FROM     Contact WHERE Id = :id];

 public Pagereference redirect(){
        PageReference redirect = new PageReference('/apex/mypage');
        redirect.setRedirect(true); 
        return redirect;
  }
 }
}
```

<---------------------mypage----------------------->

```
<apex:page controller="mycontroller">
<apex:inputField id="phoneId" value="{!Contact.phone}"/>
</apex:page>
```

here I am not able to get the value of contact.phone! it comes in as empty without any value. I am trying to communicate between two windows here maybe the current page does not give it since it is loaded after. I need help. Kindly suggest any other way to obtain my phone number in mypage. 
NOTE: This is lightning and not classic. Dunno if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A small change in controller can make it work

```
global class mycontroller{
public Contact contact {get;set;}

 public mycontroller(){
  Id id = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
  contact= (id == null) ? new Contact() :[SELECT AccountId, Phone FROM     Contact WHERE Id = :id];

 public Pagereference redirect(){
        Id recId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        PageReference redirect = new PageReference('/apex/mypage?id='+recId );
        redirect.setRedirect(true); 
        return redirect;
  }
 }
}
```